# MCP2515 CAN bus with Arduino

Tags: arduino-uno, pins, can-bus

I'm using MCP2515 CAN controller and TJA1050 transceiver. I want to send some square waves to TJA1050 with digital write and delay instruction of Arduino. How can I do that? I also read the MCP2515's datasheet. It has 5 GPIOs. Can I use these pins to send square waves to the transceiver?
Here is the library I used:[https://github.com/Seeed-Studio/CAN_BUS_Shield](http://github.com/Seeed-Studio/CAN_BUS_Shield)
The examples of this library contains a sample code as gpioread and gpiowrite but when I compile them I got error:
exit status 1
'class MCP_CAN' has no member named 'pinMode'

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why would you want to "send some square waves" to a CAN transceiver?

Answer (score 0):

This is not really a general Arduino question but...

The compiler is telling you that the member function 'pinMode' is not available. A closer look at the commit history for the library reveals that they have recently rolled back to a "working version". There is a commit with the member functions 'pinMode', 'digitalRead' and 'digitalWrite' included.

Please see: 
https://github.com/Seeed-Studio/CAN_BUS_Shield/commit/15c6bfb80a50c924a9c708117a66a66b54af5370